# Why is the scrollHeight property for elements with hidden overflow not correct?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-animations, overflow

To avoid an XY problem I should explain what I'm actually trying to do. I am attempting to animate showing and hiding `div`. My strategy is to set the `max-height` to be the computed height from the `scrollHeight` property and set `overflow: hidden`. To hide it I can set the `max-height` to `"0px"`, to show it I set it back to the `scrollHeight`, and I can animate on the `max-height` property.

To be clear, when the `div` is in the `hidden` state, it has `max-height: 0` and because of `overflow: hidden` it will not appear. In the `visible` state, it has a `max-height` that should be exactly equal to its normal height. I haven't found any other way to do this.

This does seem to work, but if the `div` is hidden initially, it doesn't work.

Here's a MWE:

Toggle 1 and Toggle 2 are identical. The only difference is that Toggle 1 starts visible, Toggle 2 doesn't. You can see that Toggle 1 works as expected, but Toggle 2 only reveals exactly half of the `div`. This is because `scrollHeight` is only half of what it should be.

Toggle 3 doesn't include `align-items: center` and it is closer, but still not quite right, off by 3px.

```js
form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
console.log('Setting form1 height to ' + form1.scrollHeight);
form1.style.maxHeight = form1.scrollHeight + "px";
function toggle1() {
  form1.classList.toggle('hide');
}

form2 = document.getElementById('form2');
console.log('Setting form2 height to ' + form2.scrollHeight);
form2.style.maxHeight = form2.scrollHeight + "px";
function toggle2() {
  form2.classList.toggle('hide');
}

form3 = document.getElementById('form3');
console.log('Setting form3 height to ' + form3.scrollHeight);
form3.style.maxHeight = form3.scrollHeight + "px";
function toggle3() {
  form3.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
}

.form3 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
}

.hide {
  max-height: 0 !important;
}

.input {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle1()">Toggle 1</button>
<div id="form1" class="form">
  <input class="input">
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle2()">Toggle 2</button>
<div id="form2" class="form hide">
  <input class="input">
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle3()">Toggle 3</button>
<div id="form3" class="form3 hide">
  <input class="input">
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<p>More content</p>
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), this should work.

> The Element.scrollHeight read-only property is a measurement of the height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen due to overflow.

The `div` doesn't have any padding or border, so it seems like this should be exactly correct.

I have no clue what's going on here. **Is it a bug?** This behavior is present in at least Firefox 90 and Chrome 88 on macOS.

**Is there something fundamental I'm not understanding that makes this impossible?**

I can't see why the `align-items: center` matters. That suggests that I don't have enough information to reason about this problem.

**Or am I just missing something else that I need to do?**

Maybe this is completely workable, but I'm just forgetting something.

---

In closing, referencing what I said before, I really just want a div that starts hidden and I can animate it opening / closing. Maybe there's a different way to do that. But at this point, I'm invested enough in the problem that I really want to know what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align-items:center` behaviour can be explained, if we look at the specification of the [scrolling area](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view-1/#scrolling-area). It says that the vertical scrolling area is from

> The element’s top padding edge.

to

> The bottom-most edge of the element’s bottom padding edge and the bottom margin edge of all of the element’s descendants' boxes, excluding boxes that have an ancestor of the element as their containing block.

Note the imbalance. Overflow below the bottom padding edge is included, but overflow above the top padding edge is not. So when the height of the flex container is 0, half of the overflow will above the top padding edge and not counted. Hence 20px instead of 40px.

The `align-items:initial` (i.e. stretch) behaviour of form3 is perhaps even more subtle. The height comes from the button, the input field is much smaller. So the button consists of an outer box generated by the button element and an inner box generated by the "Submit" text inside the button. The inner box starts below the outer box's top border and padding (3px) and is 34px high. Now the outer box is then reduced to 0px height by the max-height value, leaving the inner box to overflow that, thus placing the bottom margin edge of the inner box 37px below the top padding edge of the div.  Following the same rules as above for sizing the scrolling area, the scrollHeight is therefore 37px.

I recommend @AHaworth's workaround to avoid the problem.

---

<sub>Pixel measurements above are for Firefox. Chromium's content box measurements are slightly smaller, but follow the same rules.</sub>

Comment: Excellent, thank you for that breakdown! This is the answer to the question in the title, so I have accepted it, but I definitely appreciate the workaround from @AHaworth.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround would be to load form2 without its hide class but use JS to add it immediately you have read the 'correct' scrollHeight.

```
form2.classList.add('hide');
```

```js
form1 = document.getElementById('form1');
console.log('Setting form1 height to ' + form1.scrollHeight);
form1.style.maxHeight = form1.scrollHeight + "px";

function toggle1() {
  form1.classList.toggle('hide');
}

form2 = document.getElementById('form2');
console.log('Setting form2 height to ' + form2.scrollHeight);
form2.style.maxHeight = form2.scrollHeight + "px";
form2.classList.add('hide');

function toggle2() {
  form2.classList.toggle('hide');
}

form3 = document.getElementById('form3');
console.log('Setting form3 height to ' + form3.scrollHeight);
form3.style.maxHeight = form3.scrollHeight + "px";

function toggle3() {
  form3.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
}

.form3 {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s linear;
}

.hide {
  max-height: 0 !important;
}

.input {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 28px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle1()">Toggle 1</button>
<div id="form1" class="form">
  <input class="input">
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle2()">Toggle 2</button>
<div id="form2" class="form">
  <input class="input">
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle3()">Toggle 3</button>
<div id="form3" class="form3 hide">
  <input class="input">
  <button class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<p>More content</p>
```

Not a full explanation I realise, but one observation is that on form3 there is still a flex - which removes the 'natural' vertical centering on the input and button so the height is less. If you remove the flex altogether the height (and centering) return.

Searching for a full explanation I suspect, but can't prove, that setting the hide through a class, albeit with important set, while max height is set inline is somehow changing the order in which the browser calculates scroll height.

Comment: Great, that works! Thank you so much. Side note, could I just use the `clientHeight` now rather than `scrollHeight`, since the entire `div` is visible now? I ask because I've added a color input and now `scrollHeight` is larger than it should be but `clientHeight` is correct.